# SSL VPN Command Line Client

Tags: linux, command-line, vpn, ssl

How can I run the Array SSL VPN client via the command line w/o using a browser?  I want to run the vpn client on a headless linux box.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you want to do. First, do you connect from a windows machine to a Linux server that you want to vpn to or are you just using Linux all-around?
Either case, you can use ssh which you most likely already run on your linux server and on the client side you can use putty.exe if you're on windows, or in linux you can open a console and type ssh, then connect to your vpn.

To get the vpn going, you need to forward and open at least a forwarding port on your local machine and on the vpn box.

Here's the syntax to vpn over ssh between to linux boxes. I use RedHat and Fedora so if yours is different, read the manual for ssh, however I think this should work.
cli># ssh -w5:5 root@hserver
srv># ifconfig tun5 10.0.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.252

Commands executed on the client:
cli># ifconfig tun5 10.0.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.252   # Client is on Linux

Once you do that, you have an active vpn on a virtual lan between the 2 machines.

You can...soft of do that with putty but you can only do it on a per port scenario.

Good luck.

Comment: My hosting provider has an internal and and external network.  I want to expose admin applications and ssh only on the internal network. The only way to connect to the internal network is via SSL Vpn.